# Redirect non https and non www to https://www with wildcard support

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i can achieve the below things..

```
https://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
```

Everything is working fine...But additionaly i want the wild card to work for example

```
https://domain.com/randomblabla.html -> https://www.domain.com/randomblabla.html
```

where **randomblabla.html** dont exists...it just show the content of index.php...before i set https redirect it was working fine..but now its redirecting to `https://www.domain.com/index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*)(\/?)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]



RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is redundant presence of front controller like rule at top. Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old 301 caches.

Comment: i tried new browser , new pc , cleared cache ..check https://youwintube.com/R7npVrBqL8A.html